# Saving records based on the Date validations in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, date, validation, plsql, overlap

I need to write a function to check the first and last date validity of the employee.

```
  ncount NUMBER;
                      SELECT
                            *
                           FROM employee emp
                           WHERE emp.name = e.name
                           and emp.dept_name = e.dept_name
                           and emp.designation = e.designation
                           and emp.name = ‘Claire’  and
                                  emp.designation = ‘MGR’  ;


  select  count(*) into nCount from employee;
```

Please let me know how can i get correct result for the previous record when no last date given.

Comment: try nvl(End_Date,e.first_date) between e.first_date and NVL(e.end_date, TO_DATE('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY') . This is to treat Null value on End_Date as a valid active period for the employee.

Comment: *'I need to write a query in Oracle PL/SQL'* - SQL is a query language, PL/SQL is a programming language. You would write a package, procedure, function, trigger, type etc in PL/SQL, not a query.

Comment: Yes.. i tend to first write a query and will test it. Then thought of including that in the Function

Comment: VN'sCorner, if I include "nvl(End_Date,e.first_date) between e.first_date and NVL(e.end_date, TO_DATE('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY') "... it is giving nCount = 0 for previous records without end_date as well for the future records without end_date.. which is not correct

Comment: Adding an additional OR condition as  or e.last_date is NULL should do the job as far as i understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The query provided seems overly complicated.Self join isn't required as we are validating existence of a record based on values from variables for certain condition.
The query below should suffice:

```
WITH employee_records as
         (SELECT  * 
          FROM employee emp
          WHERE emp.name = 'Claire' 
          and   emp.dept_name = 'SALES' 
          and   emp.designation = 'MGR'                 
   and ( First_Date between emp.first_date and NVL(emp.end_date, TO_DATE('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY')) OR
         End_Date between emp.first_date and NVL(emp.end_date, TO_DATE('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY')) OR                   
        End_Date is null)
  select  count(*) into nCount from employee_records;
```

Comment: Thanks Corner and others too. Appreciate your help on this. I tried to figure it out by writing a validation and checking if any other records are present after that given past data having no last date. It worked out.